# how to write multiple div using javascript dom

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write this html code (containing many div and each div have different class) by using javascipt Dom

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m6">
            <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                <div class="card-content white-text">
                    <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                    <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small effectively.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

check my try but its not working

```
var row1 = document.querySelector('row');
var div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.className('col s12 m6');
var div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.className('card blue-grey darken-1');
var div3 = document.createElement('div');
div3.className('card-content white-text');
var span1 = document.createElement('span');
span1.className('card-title');
var para = document.createElement('p');
var paracontent = document.createTextNode('this is new world');
para.appendChild(paracontent);
div3.appendChild(para);
div2.appendChild(div3);
div1.appendChild(div1);
row1.appendChild(div1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use [classList.add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add classes
- Use a dot (.) when querying elements by class with `querySelector()`
- Change `div1.appendChild(div1)` to `div1.appendChild(div2)`

I added some CSS to visualize result.

```js
var row1 = document.querySelector('.row');
var div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.classList.add('col', 's12', 'm6');
var div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.classList.add('card', 'blue-grey', 'darken-1');
var div3 = document.createElement('div');
div3.classList.add('card-content', 'white-text');
var span1 = document.createElement('span');
span1.classList.add('card-title');
span1.textContent = 'Card Title';
var para = document.createElement('p');
var paracontent = document.createTextNode('this is new world');
para.appendChild(paracontent);
div3.appendChild(span1);
div3.appendChild(para);
div2.appendChild(div3);
div1.appendChild(div2);
row1.appendChild(div1);
```

```css
.row {
  background: red;
  padding: 0 15px 15px;
}
.row::before {
  content: 'class="row"';
  color: white;
}
.col {
  background: white;
  padding: 0 15px 15px;
}
.col::before {
  content: 'class="col s12 m6"';
  color: white;
  color: red;
}
.blue-grey {
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 15px 15px;
}
.blue-grey::before {
  content: 'class="card blue-grey darken-1"';
  color: white;
}
.white-text {
  background: green;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
}
.card-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
  color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use `setAttribute` method for set `class` and fix your `div1.appendChild(div1);` code:

```
var row1 = document.querySelector('.row');
var div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.setAttribute("class", 'col s12 m6');
var div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.setAttribute("class", 'card blue-grey darken-1');
var div3 = document.createElement('div');
div3.setAttribute("class", 'card-content white-text');
var span1 = document.createElement('span');
span1.setAttribute("class", 'card-title');
var para = document.createElement('p');
var paracontent = document.createTextNode('this is new world');
para.appendChild(paracontent);
div3.appendChild(para);
div2.appendChild(div3);
div1.appendChild(div2);
row1.appendChild(div1);
```